# Reformatting excel data in a specific way

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that has say, 10 different columns, with a few hundred records.

e.g.

```
column1|column2|column3|column4

data    data    data    data
```

I have another sheet, a template, which has the headings arranged in a certain way, e.g.

```
column1|column2
data    data
        column3   column 4
        data      data
```

So, the template block in my second sheet has to be copied and filled in for each record.

Is there a way to do this with VBA?

I am aware this is a horrible way of doing things, however I can not convince my superior of that, and so this is all I can try and do. If this is not possible, it will just be done by hand, so I am hoping some automation is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const SHT_SRC As String = "Sheet1" 'sheet w source data
    Const SHT_DEST As String = "Sheet2" 'sheet w template
    Const RNG_COPY As String = "A1:E6" 'your template area

    Dim rngDest As Range, rngSrc As Range, rngCopy As Range

    Set rngCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHT_DEST).Range(RNG_COPY)
    Set rngDest = rngCopy.Cells(1)
    Set rngSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHT_SRC).Rows(2)

    Do While rngSrc.Cells(1).Value <> ""

        rngCopy.Copy rngDest 'copy template area
        With rngDest
            'adjust offsets to fit your template layout
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = rngSrc.Cells(1).Value
            .Offset(1, 1).Value = rngSrc.Cells(2).Value
            '...etc etc
            .Offset(5, 5) = rngSrc.Cells(10).Value
        End With

        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(rngCopy.Rows.Count + 1, 0)
        Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks having a look at this now. The template is actually in a different file...does that make a big difference? I cana import it is a sheet so both are in one file I guess. I am also unsure how this works with different field names and such...should I upload a sample to show what I mean?

Comment: If the template is in a different file, do you also want the reformatted data in that file ? Try: Set rngCopy = Workbooks("otherworkbook").Sheets(SHT_DEST).Range(RNG_COPY)  Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can read the range into an array, then parse it out via individual elements:

```
Dim dataArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer

dataArray = Range("B1:B4").Value

For i = 1 to Ubound(dataArray)/2
  Range("B2").Offset(2 * (Ceiling(i/2)-1), Ceiling((i-1)/2)) = dataArray(1, i)
Next i
```

Using this function:

```
Public Function Ceiling(ByVal X As Double) As Integer

  Ceiling = Int(X) - (X - Int(X) > 0)

End Function
```

Comment: The template it a seperate file...also I am not sure about ranges...is there a way just to do it for each line?

Comment: @Donald, you could just address the other workbook if it's in a separate file.  I don't know what you mean by 'do it for each line', my code is doing it for each line.  You just have to set the ranges right, My example ranges were based on your included sample, just change them to what you need.